# Use a PHP $_SESSION Variable and then Unset it

Tags: php, session, drupal-8

I am building a Drupal 8 site. In a module preprocess function, I'm trying to check if a `$_SESSION` variable exitss when the page loads, do something with that variable, and then unset the variable. Here is a simplified version of the code:

```php
function geolocation_filter_preprocess_page() {
  if (isset($_SESSION['blocked_submission'])) {
    $messageText = $_SESSION['blocked_submission']['text'];
    $messageType = $_SESSION['blocked_submission']['type'];
    echo $messageText . $messageType;

    unset($_SESSION['blocked_submission']);
  }
}
```

If I remove the `unset` function call, then the text prints out as expected.

The variable can't be unset unless the code execution gets into the `if` block, but then the echo isn't happening as if it didn't get into the `if` block. I thought that PHP executed linearly, so I would expect the echo statement would happen and then the `$_SESSION` variable would be unset. What am I missing?

Comment: The simplified version doesn't contain the issue.

Comment: The only additional piece is that it's wrapped in a preprocess function like so: function geolocation_filter_preprocess_page() { . ..my code... }

Comment: Yes, PHP executes linearly. There must be more to the problem than you're describing.

Comment: When I run this function exactly as printed above, it doesn't not print anything out, but it does if I remove the unset function. Is it something specific that Drupal is doing that's changing the PHP functionality?

Comment: You're checking if the Session itself is set. Please check if the array elements 'text' and 'type' are also set, if they're null or empty the echo won't output anything.

Answer (score 0):

In some some cases Unsetting a session var DOES NOT WORK unless you start the session first. may be check your code if you are referring from logged out page.
unset function works only if session_start(); is called on your script

```
 session_start();
```

In your case you can declare the session like below, you so that means your code may refer to variable that is not set so try to check also type and text before trying to output them.

```
 $_SESSION['blocked_submission'] = "";
```

also
Do NOT unset the whole `$_SESSION` with `unset($_SESSION)` as this will disable the registering of session variables through the $_SESSION superglobal.